# How to Create Bezier path with different different colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I have made sample demo for creating random path using `UIBezier` object.
I know I asked same type of question which was already asked, But I was not able to solve so.

## Code

```
@implementation RandomShape
@synthesize randomPath,size,color;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.size = 1.0;
    [self.color setStroke];
    [self.randomPath stroke];
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
       self.randomPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [self.randomPath stroke];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self.randomPath moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
      [self.randomPath setLineWidth:size];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *mytouch=[touches anyObject];
    [self.randomPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
-(void)clearRandomShape
{
    self.randomPath = nil;  //Set current path nil
    self.randomPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; //Create new path
    [self.randomPath setLineWidth:2.0];
   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

1) I have select the colour from the picker view.

Now My problem is,

-->When I select colour from the picker it change all previous line colour as it is.

(It displays last colour which I choose in all random path.)

--->My requirement is I wand different different colour's random Path.

Please help Me I am confuse.

Thank you.

Comment: draw your line in multiple segments and color each segment to your choice? I also remember reading [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cagradientlayer) which can be used to color by gradient

Comment: My another requirement is i want to draw with different different size.But when i change size of path my old path size remain as it is.Thank you help me please.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, each time the user draws - in `touchesBegan`, instead of adding more lines to your existing one, create a new path with the new properties for that path. Instead of a single `UIBezierPath`, maintain and `Array` of it. Btw, I am not providing an official answer because I code in swift3, might end up making syntax error if I try to answer in objC, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code wherever you want to create path..

```
//path 1
UIBezierPath *linePath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(275, 100)];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
shapeLayer.path = linePath.CGPath;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

//Path 2
UIBezierPath *verticalLinePath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[verticalLinePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
[verticalLinePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(275, 200)];
CAShapeLayer *horizontalLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
horizontalLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
horizontalLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
horizontalLayer.lineWidth = 2;
horizontalLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
horizontalLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
horizontalLayer.path = verticalLinePath.CGPath;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:horizontalLayer];

//Path
UIBezierPath *path3 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path3 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 300)];
[path3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(275, 300)];
CAShapeLayer *horizontalLayer3 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
horizontalLayer3.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
horizontalLayer3.fillColor = [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor;
horizontalLayer3.lineWidth = 2;
horizontalLayer3.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
horizontalLayer3.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
horizontalLayer3.path = path3.CGPath;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:horizontalLayer3];
```

Output of this code is ->

[image: it looks like this]

Comment: if you find that useful, you might want to look at the [GraphViews](https://github.com/BenOngKaiXian/GraphViews) that I made, it is not as user friendly but easier if you want to extract the logic of drawing charts to use.

Comment: I wan in objective c,please give me any suggetion in objective c

Comment: My another requirement is i want to draw with different different size.But when i change size of path my old path size remain as it is.Thank you help me please.

Comment: I do not require this type of requirement.I want when i draw random path it should be draw with selected colour.Again when i draw path with random colour it should be draw that colour,and remember that both colour should be display not one.please help me ,using demo. thank you

Comment: Sorry Sir,I am beginner so I am confuse ,could not able to integrate another complex code.Sorry :(